# json.dumps generates a string and returning it as dict is making a string inside another string, how to avoid it and get just a single string

Tags: python, django, string, response, mongoengine

```
class_object = ModelClass(title=entity_object['title'], 
                            entities_definition_key=entity_object['entities_definition_key'],
                            orderId=entity_object['orderId'],uid = json.dumps( uuid.uuid4(), 
                            cls=UUIDEncoder))
```

*ModelClass is mongoengine model class*

```
json_output = class_object.serializing_method()
final_list.append(json_output)
another_class_object = AnotherModelClass(workflowId=body['workflowId'],entities_list=final_list)
another_class_object.save()
```

*save() to mongodb*

```
final_dict={}
final_dict['entities_list'] = another_class_object.entities_list
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'entity_definition_dict':entity_definition_dict}))
```

*output-{'uid': "\"74b1900ccfbd44234563805ac0279d\""}*

Comment: Why are you calling `json.dumps()` multiple times?

Comment: the first json.dumps() is just for the uid, in the 2nd json.dumps() i am dumping a dict with multiple values other than the uid

Comment: Using `json.dumps()` multiple times is what's causing what I think your problem is. Every time you call it, you get a string, not a dict. So a string is passed into the next call, not the dict like you want.

Comment: i know the problem is json.dumps(), but i'm looking for a solution for it

Comment: You don't need to serialize it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to call `json.dumps()` on the UUID. It causes all your problems and I can't imagine a problem it would fix.

```
class_object = ModelClass(
    ...,
    uid = uuid.uuid4().hex,
)
```

Comment: it says "TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: This is why i was serializing it

Comment: `type(uuid.uuid4().hex) == str`. Are you adding the `.hex` bit.